# Reading large CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm trying to read a large csv file in Python; it has some 700 attributes and 101533 rows. I tried reading the file using `pandas.read_csv` command but it gave memory issue then I tried this solution

```
import numpy as np
with file("data.csv", "rb") as f:
   title = f.readline()  # if your data have a title line.
   data = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter=",") # if your data splitted by ","
   print np.sum(data, axis=0)  # sum along 0 axis to get the sum of every column
```

but it doesn't work for large data set however works fine for small data set. How can I read this file in python?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csv` module to load your `csv` file and use `itertools.izip()` function in order to get a generator of columns then get the first columns by `next()`.

Note that `csv.reader()` return a reader object which is an iterator like object (one shot iterable), which means that it won't waste your memory and will produce the rows on demand. 
:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip
with open("data.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    print sum(next(izip(*reader)))
```

Comment: No it doesn;t help as well. nothing happens and the cursor just moves on to the next cell

Comment: it's not giving me any error, when I click the "run cell" button it the cursor moves in the second cell

Comment: @hyeri Sorry I didn't get you, Can you add more information about your code, and tell us how you want to handle the `sum`?

Comment: I just want to read a large csv file in python for now. Sum is not necessary I was only including sum because I wanted to check if the data is loaded or not. Now when I try above solutions nothing happens and the cursor moves to second cell. I have added a screenshot in my question above

Comment: Your second cell is still `input` you need to press the enter in order to see the out put

Comment: It was taking too much time to process and I'm short of time so I'm using sample data thanks for the help :)